Use a loop to create multiple source_access_configuration resources in terraform
I have a variable (type: list of string) for external subnets. For e.g., external_subnets = ["subnet-1", "subnet-2", "subnet-3"]. The list and count could vary based on the environment. I would like to create source_access_configuration for lambda event source mapping for kafka for these subnets.
I tried the below and it gives me Unexpected attribute: An attribute named "for_each" is not expected here. Any suggestions?
source_access_configuration {
  for_each = var.external_subnets

  type = "VPC_SUBNET"
  uri  = "subnet:${each.value}"
}


It appears from your question that you are attempting to implement a dynamic block. In your situation this could be performed like:
dynamic "source_access_configuration" {
  for_each = var.external_subnets

  content {
    type = "VPC_SUBNET"
    uri  = "subnet:${source_access_configuration.value}"
  }
}

